# SQLite NOT IN query is slow

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have two tables - `Keys` and `KeysTemp`.
`KeysTemp` contains temporary data which should be merged with `Keys` using the `Hash` field.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    r.[Id]
FROM
    [KeysTemp] AS k
WHERE
    r.[Hash] NOT IN (SELECT [Hash] FROM [Keys] WHERE [SourceId] = 10)
```

I have indexes on both tables for `SourceId` and `Hash` fields:

```
CREATE INDEX [IdxKeysTempSourceIdHash] ON [KeysTemp]
(
    [SourceId],
    [Hash]
);
```

The same index for `Keys` table, but query is still very slow.
There is 5 rows in temporary table and about 60000 in the main table. Query by hash takes about 27 milliseconds, but querying this 5 rows takes about 3 seconds.

I also tried splitting index, i.e. creating different indexes for `SourceId` and `Hash`, but it works the same way. `OUTER JOIN` works even worse here. How to solve that issue?

**UPDATE**
If I remove `WHERE [SourceId] = 10` from the query it completes in 30ms, that's great, but I need this condition :)

Thanks

Comment: index keys by sourceid only and keystemp by hash only. an index cannot be used if not all components are used in the query, in the same order.

Comment: i think it is very heavy to use a not in clause with thousands of elements. it is probably better to consider common elements, and then to take the remaining ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe

```
select k.id
from keytemp as k left outer join keys as kk on (k.hash=kk.hash and kk.sourceid=10)
where kk.hash is null;
```

? Assuming, that `r` is `k`. Also have you tried `not exists`? I have no idea if it works different way…

Comment: RIGHT AND FULL OUTER JOINS are not currently supported in SQLite. When order is reversed works about 818ms.

Comment: NOT EXISTS works even worse. That's strange, let me try to play with indexes.

Comment: > But this is left outer join: Oh, sorry. Didn't notice your edit, but it's still 2731ms.

Comment: I guess not exists with the right indexes does the trick! 67ms is much better.

Comment: Well, it was meant to be left join and you failed to read my mind — shame on you. If `not exists` helps, that's probably as much as I can do. I mean, I ran out of ideas ;)

Comment: BTW. I tried outer join as well. Same performance. Also when there is lot of data in KeysTemp (around 50000 in both tables) it still works slow with both outer join and not exists. It is obviously much better than before, but still not perfectly fine :) 670ms. Is it possible to make it faster?

Comment: As I said, I ran out of ideas. After all it's just sqlite… I'm not sure what you mean by the "same performance" btw. Same as not exists or same as before?

Comment: No, it's much better than not exists. At least it works perfect when there is no much data in temp table. It takes about 670ms to process when there is about 50000 rows in temporary table. Probably that's OK, as you said it's just SQLite :)

Comment: I don't remember how much sqlite supports. Just another idea — to use a prefiltering subselect as a second source for join with `sourceid` condition. That, of course, depends on your sourceid distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are just a few new keys you could try this:

```
SELECT
    r.[Id]
FROM
    [KeysTemp] AS k
WHERE
    r.[Id] NOT IN (SELECT kt.[Id] FROM [Keys] AS k1
                   INNER JOIN [KeysTemp] AS kt ON kt.Hash = k1.Hash
                   WHERE k1.[SourceId] = 10)
```

`KeysTemp` should have an index on the `Hash` column and `Keys` on the `SourceId` column.

Comment: It works, but it takes about 251ms. Still not perfect. What about indexes?

Comment: `KeysTemp` on `Hash` and `Keys` on `SourceId`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
SELECT
    r.[Id]
FROM 
    [KeysTemp] AS k
WHERE
    r.[Id] NOT IN (SELECT A.[Id] FROM [KeysTemp] AS A, [Keys] AS B WHERE B.[SourceId] = 10 AND A.[Hash] == B.[Hash])
```

You list all elements in KeysTemp (few) that exist in Keys, then take the not these ones in KeysTemp